# How to make a model based on a Migration file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, model

I have already create a migration, and I want to make a model based on the migration file.

Is this possible? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do that. The furthest you can go so far is creating a migration and a model at the same time by running:

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -m
```