# How to make a Migration file based on a model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, migration

What if I have some model, with non-default features (like soft delete or custom id name) and want to create a Migration file from it, which would have all these properties in it? So here is my model:

```
class Test extends Model
{
   use SoftDeletes;

   protected $primaryKey = 'test_id';
   protected $table = 'my_flights';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

And I want my Migration file to be based on it. But when I use command `php artisan make:migration create_test(s)_table` (I tried both `test` and `tests`) also with parameters `--create` or `--table` I get the Migration file as there was not any model:

```
class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }  ...
```

Comment: There is no native support for this in Laravel, but there might be third-party packages.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir So by default should I track the same properties twice: one in a model file and one in a Migration file? In this case what if I set custom primary key name in a model and other name in a Migration file (sorry, I am new on this and have not tested it by myself yet)?

Comment: Yes, you have to keep them in sync yourself.

Comment: Usually you won't need to 'track' properties on the model, as the Model class will get most of it directly from the database metadata. Eloquent ORM is all about convention over configuration. You only need to put on your model special conditions, like properties that doesn't follow the conventions and relevant data type castings.

Comment: @Malta Hmm.. Thanks for the hint. I didn't know that I have to put in my model only properties that doesn't follow the conventions. Now I need to rethink the use of `eloquent`)).

Comment: Eloquent follows the active record pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In normal development, the migration precedes the model details.  The migration contains the schema definitions, not the model. Eloquent models follow the active record pattern and do not contain type definitions for columns.  If following naming conventions, you do not need to specify anything about your table or columns in the model.

Nothing about the make:migration command will pull anything from existing models or database tables.  There is a package out there to support creating migrations from an existing database schema: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator but not from a model itself.

Comment: Mainly what I want to do is to **not** track the same properties twice in a  different files (Model and Migration). So In the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703394/how-to-make-a-model-based-on-a-migration-file-in-laravel) I found out that it is impossible to create a model form migration, so I thought maybe inverse order is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by tracking properties?  Where in your model are you tracking properties?

Comment: For example: `protected $primaryKey = 'test_id';  protected $table = 'my_flights';`. So if I want my Migration file to be similar to the model, I have to put the same values in it also. And when i want to change e.g. primary key name, I have to do changes in both files.

Comment: Well, neither $table nor $primaryKey are necessary if you follow naming conventions, but even so, I'd hardly call that tracking properties in both..

Comment: Please, edit your answer by adding this comment in it and the comment from the question, and I'll accept it ;)