# How can I get a property of my Eloquent Model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How could I check against one of the properties of my Permission model? I'm currently using a string to check if my user has a permission with the title $permission. But I would like to replace that string 'title' with a reference to the property in my Permission model. So that when I change the property in my permission model it changes trough my entire application. I could use constants for the properties as well and use those in my migrations but I was wondering if there is a way without using constants?

In my User Model

```
public function hasPermission(string $permission)
{
    return $this->permissions->contains('title', $permission);
}
```

My Permission Model. I didn't implement a fillable since I only make these with a Seeder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
    const SUPER = 'super';
    const ADMIN = 'admin';
    const DEVELOPER = 'developer';
    const NONE = 'none';
    public static $types = [self::SUPER, self::ADMIN, self::DEVELOPER, self::NONE];
}
```

Comment: How can you use constant if you will change that property value in the future ? Why not just declare a private variable on that model and use it as a property as a reference.

Comment: Could I use that private variable to define the name of the column when making my migrations?  So in this line $table->string('title');

Comment: Aah okay, I just read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339124/how-to-make-a-migration-file-based-on-a-model-in-laravel that migrations should define models, not the other way around. So I guess you provided a good solution then. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: I already posted it. Thanks btw :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you use constant if you will change that property value in the future ? Why not just declare a private variable on that model and use it as a property as a reference.